# Why do Files' methods use CodingErrorAction.REPORT to handle encoding errors while usual JDK behavior is to use REPLACE?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, java-8

Most JDK's methods accepting a `Charset` (or a charset name) reconfigure `Charset(De|En)coder` to handle malformed input and unmappable characters with `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE`:

- `String` ctors
- `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()`
- `InputStreamReader` ctors
- `OutputStreamWriter` ctors
- `PrintStream` ctors
- `PrintWriter` ctors
- `Formatter` ctors
- `Scanner` ctors
- etc.

Even if never stated in the Javadoc, it easy to check that in OpenJdk source code or with simple test cases:

```
private static final byte[] INVALID_UTF_8 = new byte[] {-1, 97};

@Test
public void string_uses_replacement_characters() {
    String str = new String(INVALID_UTF_8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    assertThat(str).isEqualTo("\uFFFDa");
}

@Test
public void inputStreamReader_uses_replacement_characters() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(INVALID_UTF_8);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    assertThat(br.readLine()).isEqualTo("\uFFFDa");
}
```

Some of theses classes also define methods accepting `Charset(En|De)coder` for those who want to specify another `CodingErrorAction`.

JDK 8 added the `Files` class which provides utility/factory methods to reduce the boilerplate required by few very common actions. However, all theses methods do not follow the usual behavior described earlier. (En|De)coders are not reconfigured to use `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE` and exceptions are thrown on invalid bytes & unmappable characters.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void readAllLines_throws_MIE_on_invalid_bytes() throws IOException {
    Path p = tmp.newFile().toPath();
    Files.write(p, INVALID_UTF_8);

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> Files.readAllLines(p, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .isInstanceOf(MalformedInputException.class);
}
```

Does anyone know the rational of this change and why nobody found useful to clearly state it in the Javadoc ?

Even if I think that `REPORT` is a saner default behavior, it seems really error prone to silently change this tacit agreement that has been made years ago. Most developers would expect `newBuffereReader(p, "UTF-8")` to equivalent to `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(p), "UTF-8"))` which is not true.

Note: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143997 seems related to my question.

Comment: This wasn't documented before, and it it still not explicitely documented. So I'm not sure how we could answer how something that isn't documented changed. You shouldn't have relied on it in the first place.

Comment: Only existing code has to stay compatible with older versions. New code can behave differently, that's why the new code was added in the first place.

Comment: @Tunaki: I know it wasn't documented. Nevertheless, during the last 10+ years java developers got accustomed to the 'usual behavior': methods dealing why encoding does not throw encoding-related exceptions useless you ask it. Anyone using any of the class I listed effectively rely on this undocumented behavior. I find really surprising that this change of mind is not emphasized in the documentation (both in new API which 'break' the 'usual contract' and old API which seems to be considered error prone since REPLACE-by-default has been superseded by REPORT-by-default)

Comment: @Holger: I am not saying that this change is not legitimate. From a technical point of view, I perfectly agree with you. I am trying to understand what motivated this change (is it to force developer to think about encoding errors ? To avoid 'files full of replacement characters that no one notice' ?) and why it is not documented ?

Comment: You should be aware that there are changes as, e.g. if you don’t specify an encoding, the new API’s default encoding is UTF-8 rather than the old “platform default encoding”. And UTF-8 really means “UTF-8”, not “modified UTF-8”.

Comment: @Holger: s/Platform encoding/UTF-8/ is a perfectly documented change. `Files.write(p, Arrays.asList("❤"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` throwing an exception rather than outputting a replacement character isn't one. I am not ranting about this change, I am trying to understand the rational behind the new choice and why nobody complains about  lack of documentation.

Comment: I don't see any actual problem here. Old APIs are backwards-compatible, new ones follow better practices learned over the years.

Comment: @Clément MATHIEU: These are two different things, the new API having a different behavior (about which you agree that it’s better) and the deficiencies in the documentation. Regarding the documentation, you can’t say that nobody complains about it when you already found a bug report about it yourself.

Comment: Also, asking for more specs to be expanded means that the implementation becomes more constrained. In this case it might be ok, but in others it might be undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems really error prone to silently change this tacit agreement that has been made years ago. Most developers would expect

There is no *tacit agreement*. If there were then all implementation details would implicitly be part of the specification and this would happen:

[[image: xkcd workflow]
 (source xkcd.com)](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

So please don't rely on spacebar heating (unless specified).

A prominent example where behavior that was not guaranteed by the spec was changed in the past were the `Arrays.sort` and `Collections.sort` methods. In the past they tolerated Comparators or equals implementations that violated the transitivity requirement mandated by the spec. When the merge sort implementation was changed to TimSort an exception was added that reported violations of the requirement. This was backwards-incompatible but within spec since such comparators cannot exist within the spec.

So in principle the devs could even have changed the old implementations. But for the sake of backwards compatibility and because there was no pressing need to do so they elected to only change the behavior to better, saner practices on new APIs.

New APIs are an evolution over old APIs. Streams are not Collections are not Enumerations. ByteChannels are not IOStreams.

Comment: Technically I agree with you, it is perfectly fine. From a stewardship point of view, it would be really nice to document such changes. If one decides to change a default behaviour while introducing a new API, their was most likely something wrong with the old one (and there was). If it was wrong and important enough to change it and introduce some 'inconsistencies' across the JDK, why not document that all old APIs use a dangerous behaviour and the new one prefer correctness rather than resilience ?

Comment: You're talking about changes. But the old APIs are not changed. The new APIs are new and thus also not changed. So there is no change to document.